# The rest Api returns data but it is not showing up on the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to fetch data from the rest api that I made. The api returns data but the angular fails to load it. I could see the data being passed from the network tab in developer tools.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="productsApp">
    <div ng-controller="productsController">

            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="p in products">
                    <td>{{p.productName}}</td>
                    <td>{{p.productCode}}</td>
                    <td>{{p.releaseDate | date}}</td>
                    <td>{{p.price | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/App.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/http.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/service.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Service.js

```
(function () {
    angular.module("productService", ["ngResource"]).
    factory("product", function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:55755/api/products/:id');
    });
}());
```

App.js

```
var app = angular.module("productsApp", ["productService"]);

app.controller("productsController", function ($scope, product) {

    $scope.products = product.query();
});
```

Comment: Why do you define a service as a module - `productService`? And more important, why dont you mark right answers? I see 9 questions on your profile but you did not marked one right answer.

Comment: I didn't know about marking right answers. Apologies. @lin

Comment: would this work for you? https://plnkr.co/edit/MUuquMfN0PtEwg94VWcR?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

While `query()` returns a promise you can do it like this. Just inject a callback function which is executed in the promised part automatically.

```
product.query(function (products) {
   $scope.products = products;
});
```

#### >> [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/11boyfzd/)

Comment: have you tried to `console.log(products);` whats the output?

Comment: Did, It returned an array of json objects

Comment: @ankurchavda Nice, so it should work for you. What's not working atm?

Comment: Yes it should. However, the data is not showing up on the page

Comment: I added an fiddle demo into the answer and it just works fine. Please compare it with your codes.

Comment: was out for a while, will check and let you know

Comment: It worked fine with this url when I tried earlier today, but does not work with the webapi that I made. Anyways thanks for your help